# FirebaseUI crashes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am making a simple chat app integrating Firebase Auth, Firebase Database, FirebaseUI. 
After integrating FirebaseUI, my app crashes with following debug message -

> java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm' appears.......

FirebaseUI code in MainActivity.java -

[image: Screenshot]

My dependencies -

- compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1
- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
- compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
- compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
- compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'

Comment: Have you enabled authentication in Firebase Consle?

Comment: Don't show a screenshot of your code. Instead edit your question to show the code as text.

Comment: 1. Yes I have enabled it. 2. I have spent entire hour to show the code as text but StackOverflow's intent error won't go away. The code is properly indented by Android Studio,